# web application using request.sendrequest under apache httpd + tomcat

Tags: redirect

in spring mvc action, retruned "redirect:/toLogin"

just in the tomcat, we could get the right redirect location, such as '192.168.1.10/toLogin'

but when i using the apache httpd server to proxy request to tomcat (apache's ip 192.168.1.2 , tomcat is 192.168.1.10)

i visit '192.168.1.2'  could get the index page.
but when i click some link which need to be redirect to the login page , i just get the location '192.168.1.10/toLogin' (the right location is '192.168.1.10/toLogin')

this is caused by the tomcat send redirect request under its address.

is there any way to redirect to the right location.
or maybe i configured wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I change http_proxy to mod_jk connector 

I think mod_jk has synchronized the info int request and response

Answer (score 0):

I change http_proxy to mod_jk connector

I think mod_jk has synchronized the info int request and response